# Colum headers not visible in GridExporter add-on for Vaadin 23

Tags: java, vaadin

hi i installed export grid for vaadin 23 the add-on is ok except when i exported in any format not insert the colunm name in first row only blank one for a column. I used a persistence Tuple class in grid to handler a generic query in table.

below an example

```
private Grid<Tuple> grd_report;



    private void buildReport(ReportEntity re)
    {
        rg=new ReportGen(re);
        List<Tuple> rows = rg.generate();
        List<TupleElement<?>> elements = rows.get(0).getElements();
        grd_report.removeAllColumns();
//      HeaderRow headerRow;
        if(grd_report.getHeaderRows().size()>0)
            grd_report.getHeaderRows().clear();
        else
            grd_report.appendHeaderRow();
        
    HeaderRow headerRow = grd_report.getHeaderRows().get(0);
        
        for ( int idxCol = 0; idxCol < elements.size(); idxCol++ )
        {
            Integer xx=idxCol;
            String ColumName=elements.get(idxCol).getAlias();
            Grid.Column<Tuple> Column = grd_report.addColumn(te->te.get(xx)).setHeader(ColumName).setSortable(true).setKey(ColumName);
            if(idxCol==0)
                Column.setFooter("Total:" + rows.size());
            headerRow.getCell(Column).setComponent(createFilterHeader(ColumName));
            Column.setResizable(true);
        }
        
        grd_report.setItems(rows);
        grd_report.setPageSize(30);
        
    }



    private void exportFile(ComboItem ci)
    {
        
        Anchor download=null;
        exporter = GridExporter.createFor(grd_report);
        exporter.setTitle(cmb_reports.getValue().getName());
        exporter.setFileName("Export_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMM").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        exporter.setAutoAttachExportButtons(false);
```

can you help me?
Massimiliano

can you resolved then problem

Comment: Not what you asked. (1) Are you sure you want the order `yyyyddMM` in the file name? That is unusual. (2) Do not use `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s so troublesome and also long outdated. Use `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern"uuuuddMM"))`.

Answer (score 2):

The add-on does not support component headers:

```
Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
Column<String> col1 = grid.addColumn(x -> x).setHeader("Has text header");
Column<String> col2 = grid.addColumn(x -> x).setHeader(new Span("Text header"));
System.out.println(GridHelper.getHeader(grid, col1));
System.out.println(GridHelper.getHeader(grid, col2)); //prints an empty string
```

<del>Since Vaadin does not provide an API for retrieving the header</del> *(see edit)*, we used [GridHelpers](https://github.com/FlowingCode/GridHelpers), which implements a [workaround](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1496#issuecomment-577553691) that is only able to retrieve string headers:

> use a lot of reflection to dig out Renderer from the column, and then Template from the Renderer.

That is implemented [here](https://github.com/FlowingCode/GridHelpers/blob/9cffcc26c94d52cfd8787137a912eaba16b780ce/src/main/java/com/flowingcode/vaadin/addons/gridhelpers/HeaderFooterGridHelper.java). `GridExporter` just delegates into it ([source](https://github.com/FlowingCode/GridExporterAddon/blob/7c195336577b262ca47412cbe0aa3eee4f08b526/src/main/java/com/flowingcode/vaadin/addons/gridexporter/BaseInputStreamFactory.java#L64-L67))

```
 protected List<Pair<String,Column<T>>> getGridHeaders(Grid<T> grid) {
    return exporter.columns.stream().map(column -> ImmutablePair.of(GridHelper.getHeader(grid,column),column))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

`GridExporter` does not (currently) allow setting an "export header" independently from the `Grid` header.

I created an [enhancement request](https://github.com/FlowingCode/GridExporterAddon/issues/33) for that.

==EDIT==

Vaadin 23.2 does provide `column.getHeaderComponent()`, and it's also possible to do `getHeaderComponent().getElement().getTextRecursively()`, but in most cases it will not be enough, thus the need for a custom export header still stands.